# ASP - How to insert string variable in long string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, variables

I want to insert string variable(**myVar**) in this string how to do this ?

```
 breadCrumbLit.Text = $@"<a href='VARIABLE HERE'>VARIABLE HERE</a>
    i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
    <span> VARIABLE HERE </span>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
    <a href='/EN/Pages/SGHG.aspx'> VARIABLE HERE </a>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>​ 
    <span>​ VARIABLE HERE </span>";
```

[image]

Syntax give me error, where i'm Wrong ?

Comment: Is this C# or VB.NET? What is the error message?

Comment: C#, syntaxis is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a compilation error for your code is because the `@` is not for the correct string. You are using `@` to specify that your string code is in multiple lines but in your code you have different strings.

This is yours:

```
                         #1                 #2        #3
breadCrumbLit.Text = @"<a href='/EN'>'" + myVar +  "'</a>
 <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>";
```

put the `@` at the string that has multiple lines:

```
breadCrumbLit.Text = "<a href='/EN'>'" + myVar +  @"'</a>
 <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>";
```

A better approach all together will be to use `string.Format`:

```
breadCrumbLit.Text = string.Format(@"<a href='/EN'>'{0}'</a>
                                     <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>",myVar);
```

Or the C# 6.0 syntax for it:

```
breadCrumbLit.Text = =  $@"<a href='/EN'>'{myVar}'</a>
                           <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>";
```

---

For your editing of the question: you are missing to wrap your parameters with `{}`. Check this:

```
string variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5;
variable1 = variable2 = variable3 = variable4 = variable5 = "some text";

var Text = $@"<a href='{variable1}'>{variable2}</a>
    i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
    <span> {variable3} </span>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>
    <a href='/EN/Pages/SGHG.aspx'> {variable4} </a>
    <i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>​ 
    <span>​ {variable5} </span>";
```

Comment: @Gohyu - Did this solve your problem or do you need still help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape:

```
breadCrumbLit.Text = "<a href=\"/EN\">" + myVar + 
"</a> <i class=\"fa fa-angle-right\"></i>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Code for this. I found no syntax error on this.

```
breadCrumbLit .Text = @"<a href='/EN'>'" + myVar + "'</a><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>";
```

Comment: But he uses `@` to be able to insert line breaks

Comment: see my post, please